# How to call spring boot MessageMapping using okhttp3 Websocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I have created a spring boot Messaging endpoint and need to create an android chat app and am wondering how I can manage to call those endpoints using okttp Websocket client which does not seem to have a way to add api endpoints like this javascript code.

[image]

And here is my spring boot endpoints

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebMessageConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker( "/user");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addEndpoint("/ws")
                 .withSockJS()
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");

    }
    
    }
```

And here is my OkHttp client code

public class StompWs {

```
private String SERVER_PATH="ws://mydomain.com:8443/MyContex/ws";
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        new StompWs().run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private WebSocket webSocket;
public void run() throws Exception {

       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SERVER_PATH).build();
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new SocketListener());
       
}
 
private String getData()
{
    MessageModel message=new MessageModel();
    message.setMessage("Hello");
    message.setRecipientId("1");
    message.setSenderId("2");
    
    
    return new Gson().toJson(message);
}
      private class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
       

                try {
                   webSocket.send(getData());
                   /**I need equivalent of this
                   
                   stompClient.subscribe(
      "/user/1/queue/messages",// I need java code to do this
      onMessageReceived
                   */
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("succesfully connected:"+response.toString());//this message execute well
                
              

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text);

              System.out.println("on message:"+text);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t,
                Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
            System.out.println("on message:"+t.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it but you probably want to start from something like https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid

Comment: @YuriSchimke Let me have a look at it

Comment: @NemugaDev can you please share the solution.